# Microsoft.WebSockets WebSocketHandler Secure SSL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, websocket

I created an MVC web application and embedded an WebSockets chat server. I can deploy this app to an secure endpoint, but how can I get the WebSocketHandler to listen to a wss:// endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your web app has a HTTPS binding, WSS should be able of connecting. Check your IIS configuration, enable the port TCP 443 with HTTPS binding and a certificate in the bindings configuration.

Now if you access the web app through HTTPS, you should connect via WSS without problems.

If you access via HTTP, the certificate is self signed, and you didn't accept it in the browser before, it will probably fail. Watch out with that.

Comment: Thank you. I succeeded. But I had indeed a self signed certificate which didn't work with Safari but did work in Chrome. Have to get a trusted server certificate.